# Why this code doesn't work? (Variable objects key and value)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var elems = [];
var at1 = $(indx).attr('class'); //or any string
var at2 = $(indx).html(); //or any string
elems.push({
  at1: at2
});
```

The output I get is:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE4Ba.png)
Why can not I set the key as a string?

Answer (score 4):

The way you create an object, the key is going to be interpreted literally as `"at1"` string. In your case you need to do it slightly more verbose:

```
var at1 = $(indx).attr('class');
var at2 = $(indx).html();

var obj = {};
obj[at1] = at2;

elems.push(obj);
```

... or using ES2015 [computed property name](http://New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015):

```
var at1 = $(indx).attr('class');
var at2 = $(indx).html();

elems.push({
  [at1]: at2
});
```